# Route Planner: how did Google camera car plan their driving route?

Tags: routes, gps, mapping, scanning

I was wondering if anyone knows how Google camera car (for the street view scanning) did their route planning? Below are my conditions:

- Let's suppose I have a couple of cameras mounted on my van
- Mounted cameras will take a sequence of images as I drive around
- I want to get an efficient route planner to cover the entire area of the town road
- Every single part of the town should be covered (by driving) but maximize efficiency by minimizing the driving time
- I tried some available route planners but all of them require physical address of start and stop points, which I don't have

P.S. I mean, I guess I could just use one of those running apps to keep track of GPS while driving, but I am trying to do get a more sophisticated plan before starting the scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure they used a multi stop route planner for this. How about splitting the area into 4 parts (for example) and then inserting a number of house numbers in each street? This is how our customers do this. It forces the route to visit all the streets in your area.